# Uso de delegates en C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tengo el siguiente código, sacado de un Script de Unity para reproducir vídeo:

```
public delegate void VideoEnd();
public VideoEnd OnEnd;
```

Luego, cuando un vídeo finaliza, se genera el siguiente evento:

```
if (OnEnd != null)
    OnEnd();
```

Lo que yo necesito, es (no si se es declarar, o cual seria el nombre de lo que quiero hacer) asignar a OnEnd la función de Stop(), o sea, que cuando salta el evento del delegate, se genere un stop.
Cual es el método correcto para utilizar delegates en este caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el ejemplo de tu código lo que tendrías que hacer es esto:

```
OnEnd = Stop;
```

La única regla para que esto funcione es que Stop este declarada como

```
void Stop(){
   // Aqui va la implementacion
}
```

Si deseas que OnEnd deje de mandar llamar Stop solo asigna OnEnd a null

```
OnEnd = null;
```